# Firebase Authentication: Cannot destructure property 'user'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am getting this errors in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , *hooks_use_auth_listener__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.default)(...)' as it is undefined.

and

> The above error occurred in the <App> component:
>
> at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46:75)

I don't know what the problem is but i cant see any of the pages in the localhost.

**App.js**

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import \* as ROUTES from "./constants/routes";
import UserContext from "./context/user";
import useAuthListener from "./hooks/use-auth-listener";

const Login = lazy(() =\> import("./pages/login"));
const SignUp = lazy(() =\> import("./pages/signup"));
const Dashboard = lazy(() =\> import("./pages/dashboard"));
const NotFound = lazy(() =\> import("./pages/notfound"));

function App() {
const { user } = useAuthListener();

return (
\<UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}\>
\<Router\>
\<Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}\>
\<Routes\>
\<Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} element={\<Login /\>} /\>
\<Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} element={\<SignUp /\>} /\>
\<Route path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} element={\<Dashboard /\>} /\>
\<Route element={\<NotFound /\>} /\>
\</Routes\>
\</Suspense\>
\</Router\>
\</UserContext.Provider\>
);
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import firebaseContext from "./context/firebase";
import { app, FieldValue } from "./lib/firebase";
import "./styles/app.css";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
\<firebaseContext.Provider value={{ app, FieldValue }}\>
\<App /\>
\</firebaseContext.Provider\>
);
```

**firebase.js**

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

//here want to import the seed file

import { seedDatabase } from "../seed";

const config = {
apiKey: "api-key",
authDomain: "auth-domain",
projectId: "project-id",
storageBucket: "storage-bucket",
messagingSenderId: "messaging-sender-id",
appId: "app-id"
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const { FieldValue } = firebase.firestore;

//here want to call the seed file (only ONCE)
seedDatabase(app);

export { app, FieldValue };
```

**use-auth-listener.js**

```
/\* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps \*/
// Checks if a user is logged in or Logged out.

import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import firebaseContext from "../context/firebase";

export default function useAuthListener() {
const \[user, setUser\] = useState.apply(
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser"))
);
const { firebase } = useContext(firebaseContext);

useEffect(() =\> {
const listener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) =\> {
if (authUser) {
// We have an authuser so we can store the user in localStorage.
localStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(authUser));
setUser(authUser);
} else {
// We don't have an authuser so we clear the localStorage.
localStorage.removeItem("authUser");
}
});

    return () => listener();

}, \[firebase\]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer that was making the problem for me.
I just changed this

```
function App() {
    const { user } = useAuthListener();
```

from App.js file to this

```
function App() {
    const { user } = useAuthListener() || {};
```

By using the `|| {}` syntax, we can ensure that user is an object even if it is undefined. This will prevent the "cannot destructure property 'user'...as it is undefined" error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think The issue might be because useState.apply is being used instead of useState. The apply method is used for calling a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array, which is not the case here.

Try using

```
const \[user, setUser\] = useState(
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser"))
);
```